# Filling in missing dates with most recent data in data frame in R

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate, data-transform

I have a data frame with country, date, identifier, cumulative_identifier, cumulative_country. Country, data, and identifier are grouped. I, however, have countries, and identifiers with missing dates. These are countries that have not submitted data for these days for this identifier. I would like to include these dates, but use the data from the most recent submission.

The data must be grouped by country, date, and identifier. For example give a data frame below.

```
country       date        identifier       cumulative_id         cumulative_country
France      2021-03-20       B.1.1.7                 3528                     12158
France      2021-03-15       B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-15       B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-14       B.1.2                     48                     12140
Morocco     2021-03-16       B.1.1.7                  232                      5636
Morocco     2020-03-01       B.1.1.7                  220                      5624
```

In the example above, there are many dates missing. The dates added would use the information from the most recent submission. So France and Morocco should look like this:

```
country          date        identifier       cumulative_id         cumulative_country
France      2021-03-20         B.1.1.7                 3528                     12158
France      2021-03-19         B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-18         B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-17         B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-16         B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-20         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-19         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-18         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-17         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-16         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-15         B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-14         B.1.2                     48                     12140
France      2021-03-13         B.1.2                     48                     12140
Morocco     2021-03-20       B.1.1.7                    232                      5636
Morocco     2021-03-19       B.1.1.7                    232                      5636
Morocco     2021-03-18       B.1.1.7                    232                      5636
Morocco     2021-03-17       B.1.1.7                    232                      5636
Morocco     2021-03-16       B.1.1.7                    232                      5636
Morocco     2021-03-15       B.1.1.7                    220                      5624
...
Morocco     2021-03-01       B.1.1.7                    220                      5624
```

This is what I have tried with Aurèle's suggestion:
The resulting date frame, however, is identical to the original, with no changes. Again, it takes 8 minutes to complete, since there are already over 100,000 observations in the dataset.

```
horizontal$date <- as.Date(horizontal$date)


df <- df %>% 
  complete(nesting(country, pango_lineage), date = full_seq(date, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(country, pango_lineage) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(cum_country_pang, cum_country), zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(cum_country_pang))
```

[image]

Comment: why does Morocco go to 2020-03-20 instead of 2020-03-16?

Comment: It's pretending that 2021-03-20 is the current date. So each country should have a submission for each identifier for each date. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr` `complete` and `zoo` `na.locf` (Last Observation Carried Forward):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  complete(nesting(country, identifier), date = full_seq(date, 1)) %>% 
  group_by(country, identifier) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(cumulative_id, cumulative_country), zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(cumulative_id))

#> # A tibble: 398 x 5
#> # Groups:   country, identifier [3]
#>    country identifier date       cumulative_id cumulative_country
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <date>             <int>              <int>
#>  1 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-15          3520              12150
#>  2 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-16          3520              12150
#>  3 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-17          3520              12150
#>  4 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-18          3520              12150
#>  5 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-19          3520              12150
#>  6 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-20          3528              12158
#>  7 France  B.1.2      2021-03-14            48              12140
#>  8 France  B.1.2      2021-03-15            50              12142
#>  9 France  B.1.2      2021-03-16            50              12142
#> 10 France  B.1.2      2021-03-17            50              12142
#> # ... with 388 more rows
```

---

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text =
'country       date        identifier       cumulative_id         cumulative_country
France      2021-03-20       B.1.1.7                 3528                     12158
France      2021-03-15       B.1.1.7                 3520                     12150
France      2021-03-15       B.1.2                     50                     12142
France      2021-03-14       B.1.2                     48                     12140
Morocco     2021-03-16       B.1.1.7                  232                      5636
Morocco     2020-03-01       B.1.1.7                  220                      5624
', header = TRUE)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does indeed work with the mock dataset that I gave, but for my larger dataset it doesn't work. I have 880 different identifiers, 200 countries, over 365 different dates. Each time I run, it take about 7 minutes, but the resulting data frame does not have the missing dates included. Is there anything that I could be missing?

Comment: I will post a photo of the dataset I am using and what I have tried. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `zoo::na.locf`, just use `tidyr::fill`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    complete(nesting(country, identifier), date = full_seq(date, 1)) %>% 
    group_by(country, identifier) %>% 
    fill(c(cumulative_id, cumulative_country), .direction = "down") %>%
    filter(!is.na(cumulative_id))
#> # A tibble: 398 x 5
#> # Groups:   country, identifier [3]
#>    country identifier date       cumulative_id cumulative_country
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <date>             <int>              <int>
#>  1 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-15          3520              12150
#>  2 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-16          3520              12150
#>  3 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-17          3520              12150
#>  4 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-18          3520              12150
#>  5 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-19          3520              12150
#>  6 France  B.1.1.7    2021-03-20          3528              12158
#>  7 France  B.1.2      2021-03-14            48              12140
#>  8 France  B.1.2      2021-03-15            50              12142
#>  9 France  B.1.2      2021-03-16            50              12142
#> 10 France  B.1.2      2021-03-17            50              12142
#> # … with 388 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>